# Python mechanize on Raspbian

Tags: python, ssl, mechanize, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am writing a python (2.7.3) script that will regularly log in to Mint.com from a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian. However, my script is hanging on the SSL handshake The following code runs fine on OSX running Python 2.7.3:

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("https://wwws.mint.com/login.event")
```

However, when I run the exact same code on my Raspberry Pi running Python 2.7.3,`open` never returns. When I cancel the run (`ctrl+c`), I get a long traceback, ending with:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 305, in do_handshake
  self._sslobj.do_handshake()
```

I don't have any issues opening `https://www.mint.com`, so it seems that the issue is the `login.event`, which is necessary in order to submit the login credentials.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced an issue like this with Ubuntu LTS 12.04. I tried the same code on a machine running latest Mint Debian Edition (subscribing to incoming repository) and the issue was resolved.

Comment: I did the same in the end.